# Linear SVM vs Nonlinear SVM high dimensional data

Tags: svm, data-mining, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a project where I use Spark Mllib Linear SVM to classify some data (l2 regularization). I have like 200 positive observation, and 150 (generated) negative observation, each with 744 features, which represent the level of activity of a person in different region of a house.

I have run some tests and the "areaUnderROC" metric was 0.991 and it seems that the model is quite good in classify the data that I provide to it.
I did some research and I found that the linear SVM is good in high dimensional data, but the problem is that I don't understand how something linear can divide my data so well.

I think in 2D, and maybe this is the problem but looking at the bottom image, I am 90% sure that my data looks more like a non linear problem[image]

So it is normal that I have good results on the tests? Am I doing something wrong? Should I change the approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you question is about 'why linear SVM could classfy my hight Dimensions data well even the data should be non-linear'
some data set look like non-linear in low dimension just like you example image on right, but it is literally hard to say the data set is definitely non-linear in high dimension because a nD non-linear may be linear in (n+1)D space.So i dont know why you are 90% sure your data set is non-linear even it is a high Dimension one.
At the end, I think it is normal that you have a good test result in test samples, because it indicates that your data set just is linear or near linear in high Dimension or it wont work so well.Maybe cross-validation could help you comfirm that your approach is suitable or not.